# How to override default_scope in ActiveAdmin in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, default-scope

In a resource registered with ActiveAdmin, I have the following default_scope defined for the model:

```
default_scope :order => 'activities.updated_at DESC'
```

This apparently prevents me from being able to change the sorting on the resource's index page by clicking on the column titles.  Is there a way to keep this default scope but get Active Admin sorting to work?

Answer (score 47):

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  controller do
    def scoped_collection
      Post.unscoped
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: this isn't working for me, it appears to still be scoped.

Comment: turns out I had scoped_collection defined again further down the file.

Answer (score 7):

```
scope('all', default: true) { |scope| scope.where(...) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out this solution.

```
#/admin/user.rb
controller do
  # for index page
  def active_admin_collection
    User.unscoped { super }
  end

  # for show, edit
  def resource
    User.unscoped { super }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  scope_to do
   Class.new do
    def self.cookies
     Cookie.unscoped
    end
   end
  end
```

more here: http://blogs.burnsidedigital.com/2012/09/ignoring-default_scope-in-activeadmin/

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to scope the activities or just order them, because this call only orders them, it is not actually scoping the query in the strictest idea.

From what I know of `ActiveAdmin` and from what their documentation states, you should probably set it up like this.

```
  class Activities < ActiveRecord::Base
    default_scope lambda { where :updated_at => true }
  end
```